# What can be a unique identifier for user account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase, icloud

I need to save on server some unique identifier for user account, so than I can determinate on another user device, that account identifier had been already setted. But I don't know what can be a unique id for account and how to get it programmicaly?

Edit:

I'm moving app from paid version to freemium(with in-app-purchases). And I need to save all users that had bought app. So I've created server and want to save there all users. So I need unique value for account, so then user would be able to restore all purchases on his other device.

Comment: Store a file with the user's login in iCloud and have it sync to all devices that have the app?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson can yo write a code sample how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the user's email address. How you would get it would be to prompt the user for it.

Then use the usual verification where you send an email to that address with a link the user clicks that sends back an HTTP response with a unique key in it.

To do that you will need a server. Your app would connect to the server, send the user's account info and email address, and the server would compose an email to that email address including a coded clickable link.

There are likely off-the-shelf server libraries to do exactly that. I'd have to do some research to find them. That's what I suggest you do.

Comment: I think i don't need all that. I need only some unique info for account that I can get. As far as I know there is no possibility to get user email from icloud

Comment: Note that I suggested you ask the **USER** for his/her email, and then use a verification email through a server. If you don't need "all that" then you need to come up with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to support more than one device from one User, you can use the Vendor-ID, this is unique for all ios-devices:

UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor

Or as a String:

UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString.

Otherwise you should realise some kind of loginname that the user has to fill at register.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you are expecting the user to have iCloud enabled or not, but if you are expecting this, why not just check for iCloud availability by getting the value of the ubiquityIdentityToken property of NSFileManager, like this:

```
let token = NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken
```

According to the iCloudDesignGuide, "The value of the property is a unique token representing the currently active iCloud account." and is what I think you are trying to get. You should be able to use this value, even if you don't store anything in iCloud as long as you have provisioned it for the app and they are logged in and have "iCloud Drive" enabled.